# Classification using a data set contains text and numbers

Tags: r, dataset, classification, text-classification, training-data

I have the following data set `myDataSet`:

```
sentence1    sentence2    lengthofsentence1   lengthOfsentence2    label
Thank you     Thanks             9                    6              1
Hello           Hi               5                    2              2
Goodbye         Bye              7                    3              3
Many thanks   Thanks to you      11                   13             1
    .            .               .                    .              .
    .            .               .                    .              .
    .            .               .                    .              .
```

I want to use `SVM` for classification. I can create my training set just with column 3 and 4 which are numeric:

```
train_data <- myDataSet[3:4]
lables <- myDataSet[5]
train <- svm(train_data, lables, type = "C-classification")
```

but I want to know how to create a training set using all the first four columns? In fact I want to use column 1,2,3,4 which two of them are text and the rest are numeric for creating training set. I read this page: [SVM Tutorial: How to classify text in R](https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/11/svm-classify-text-r/), but It is just for the column whose type is text.

Comment: You can only feed numerical data into an SVM so you will have to find some meaningful way to represent your text data. In both `sentence1, sentence2` how many possible combinations are there? If a reasonable number, consider representing them as dummy variables. 1 for each level.

Comment: If `SVM` is not suitable for my purpose, what classification algorithm do you recommend? @Sam

Comment: `SVM` can definitely be used for purpose. You just need to conduct more research into numerically representing words. You've made a start by computing the number of characters per sentence but this approach is problematic. Many sentences will have the same number of words but could have completely different meanings!

Comment: That's why I also want to use the first two columns which are text for classification. @Sam

Comment: Please read https://www.r-bloggers.com/natural-language-processing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ways to accomplish this. Taking into account you need numerical values you can recode to achieve it. After recoding you can use SVM.
Remember to keep the equivalences.

```
# using car package
library(car)

# Recode grade "Hello" to 1
myDataSet$sentence1 <- car::recode(myDataSet$sentence1,"Hello=1")


# using dplyr recode

dplyr::recode(myDataSet, Hello = 1)


# other dplyr way for all factor columns (beware the data types)
# return only the mutated columns

dplyr::mutate_if(myDataSet, is.factor, funs(as.numeric(interaction(., drop = TRUE))))


# preserve the original columns (useful for keeping a dictionnary for later use)
dplyr::mutate_if(myDataSet, is.factor, funs(new = as.numeric(interaction(., drop = TRUE))))


# using match
oldvalues <- c("Hello", "Hi")
newvalues <- factor(c("1","2")) 
myDataSet$sentence1 <- newvalues[ match(myDataSet$sentence1, oldvalues) ]
```

Comment: You are making the assumption of a finite sentence set.

Comment: Sam , using _dplyr::mutate_if_ don't need to be worried about finite sentence sets

Comment: Ok so suppose there is a single occurrence of each sentence and their is > 100,000 data points. What then

Comment: From the data in the question my only concern was to solve the issue. If the case is 100.000 unique sentences then this approach is not the proper one and Patris should search and study about NLP and rely on specific packages for text analytics.

Comment: This is fair. But the OP didn't provide the full data as illustrated by the 3 dots therefore you cannot assume you've solved the issue without further information.

Comment: I just want to know how to use text columns with numeric columns for classification in `SVM`. I know how to use them separately, but I would like to know how to combine them.

Comment: @Patris How would one use textual columns singularly in an SVM?

Comment: I don't want use them singularly, in fact my data set is not the one I mentioned in my question, I really need to use textual columns with numeric columns in `SVM`. @Sam

Comment: The truth is, you can't feed text into an SVM.

Comment: No, it's possible. See the link I mentioned in my question. I want to use `SVM`  both for textual and numeric columns simultaneous. @Sam

Comment: Ok. Can you please show us what the return of `create_matrix` looks like on your data? This would be easier if you provided an MVCE btw.